# the call to a function does not correspond to any overload of

Tags: java, crystal-reports

I'm developing a java library to manage different kinds of barcode in Crystal Report. Crystal Report offers a sdk for Eclipse and inside a new project there are library to develop the integration between a ERP and CR. One of this library manage barcodes, but is a poor library because I can manage just a kind of barcode. I found a document to implement UFL. The document offers a simple example and thanks of that I wrote some class to manage three kinds of barcode, but there are some Crystal report function with two paramaters, and the example doesn't show how to get right implementation.  I tried to develop new classes to manage that kind of function but Always I get this message of error:"the call to a function does not correspond to any overload of 'name of function'".

For this function I tried to pass only a parameter and the application runs well. I did an overload of the method, passing two parameters, but always I've got the same message of error.

this is a part of my code

```
public final FormulaValue evaluate(FormulaValueReference[] arguments)
     throws FormulaFunctionCallException
  {

       StringValue dataStringArg = (StringValue)arguments[0].getFormulaValue();
       StringValue opzArg =(StringValue)arguments[1].getFormulaValue();

     String dataString = dataStringArg.getString();
     String opz=opzArg.getString();



    String returnVal = doTranslation(dataString,opz);

    return StringValue.fromString(returnVal);
   }

  protected abstract String translate(String inputData,String opz)
   throws InvalidBarcodeDataException;


public class CodeEAN13
  extends CodeEAN13Base
{


   public String getIdentifier()
   {
    return "barcodeean13";
  }

protected String translate(String inputData, String opz) throws InvalidBarcodeDataException {
    Integer checkDigitSubtotal;
.....
}
```

I except to show the report with that kind of barcode. CodeEAN13 class should run an algorithm to calculate a string for the barcode font.

This is the code from the libraries when the program runs and shown in the stacktrace. For each line of the stracktrace I've put the corrisponding code.

```
//com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaService.compile(SourceFile:347)

public void compile(FormulaDefinitionBase paramFormulaDefinitionBase, FormulaContext paramFormulaContext)
    throws FormulaException
  {
    if (paramFormulaDefinitionBase == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("A formula must be given.");
    }
    paramFormulaDefinitionBase.getFormulaInfo().a(paramFormulaContext);
  }

//com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaInfo.a(SourceFile:570)

void a(FormulaContext paramFormulaContext)
    throws FormulaException
  {
    if (this.jdField_try)
    {
      this.o = true;

      throw new FormulaException("JRC00000433", "", FormulaResources.a(), "RecursiveCompileDetected", this);
    }
    this.o = false;
    if (paramFormulaContext == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("A formula context must be given.");
    }
    try
    {
      this.jdField_try = true;
      jdMethod_if(paramFormulaContext);
      this.t = this.jdField_long.getFormulaValueType();
      this.jdField_do.a();//(SourceFile:570)
    }
    catch (FormulaException localFormulaException)
    {
      if ((localFormulaException.getResourceKey().equals("RecursiveCompileDetected")) && (this.o)) {
        throw new FormulaException("JRC00000434", "", FormulaResources.a(), "RecursionNotAllowed", null, localFormulaException);
      }
      throw localFormulaException;
    }
    finally
    {
      this.jdField_try = false;
      jdMethod_if();
    }
  }

//com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.r.a(SourceFile:90)
public void a()
    throws FormulaException
  {
    FormulaInfo localFormulaInfo = this.a.getFormulaInfo();
    FormulaDefinitionBase localFormulaDefinitionBase = this.a.getFormula();
    String str1 = "Formula";
    String str2 = "";
    if ((localFormulaDefinitionBase instanceof CustomFunctionDefinition))
    {
      str1 = "Custom function";
      str2 = "'";
    }
    if (if.isDebugEnabled()) {
      if.debug("Compiling " + StringUtil.toLowerCaseEng(str1) + " " + str2 + localFormulaDefinitionBase.getFormulaForm() + str2 + "...");
    }
    localFormulaInfo.invalidate();
    try
    {
      ExpressionNode localExpressionNode = o.a(this.a).a();
      localExpressionNode = this.jdField_do.jdMethod_void(localExpressionNode);//(SourceFile:90)
      localExpressionNode = this.jdField_for.c(localExpressionNode);
      localFormulaInfo.a(localExpressionNode);

      localFormulaDefinitionBase.formulaInfoUpdated();
      if (if.isInfoEnabled()) {
        if.info(str1 + " " + str2 + localFormulaDefinitionBase.getFormulaForm() + str2 + " compiled.");
      }
    }
    catch (FormulaException localFormulaException)
    {
      if (if.isInfoEnabled()) {
        if.info(str1 + " " + str2 + localFormulaDefinitionBase.getFormulaForm() + str2 + " did not compile: " + localFormulaException);
      }
      localFormulaInfo.invalidate();

      throw localFormulaException;
    }
  }
}
//com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.c.void(SourceFile:70)
 public ExpressionNode jdMethod_void(ExpressionNode paramExpressionNode)
    throws FormulaException
  {
    ExpressionNode localExpressionNode = paramExpressionNode;

    this.jdField_int = 0;
    this.jdField_for = 0;

    FormulaDefinitionBase localFormulaDefinitionBase = this.a.getFormula();
    FormulaInfo localFormulaInfo = this.a.getFormulaInfo();

    localExpressionNode = jdMethod_do(localExpressionNode);//(SourceFile:70)

    FormulaValueType localFormulaValueType = a(localFormulaDefinitionBase, localFormulaInfo, localExpressionNode);
    if ((localExpressionNode != null) && (!localFormulaValueType.equals(localExpressionNode.getFormulaValueType())))
    {
      localExpressionNode = a(localExpressionNode, localFormulaValueType);
      if ((!new) && (!localExpressionNode.getFormulaValueType().equals(localFormulaValueType))) {
        throw new AssertionError("Coercion failed!!! This should never happen.");
      }
    }
    localFormulaInfo.a(localFormulaValueType);

    return localExpressionNode;
  }

  //com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.do(SourceFile:74)
  final ExpressionNode jdMethod_do(ExpressionNode paramExpressionNode)
    throws FormulaException
  {
    try
    {
      return a(paramExpressionNode);//(SourceFile:74)
    }
    catch (StackOverflowError localStackOverflowError)
    {
      throw new FormulaException("JRC00000461", "", FormulaResources.a(), "StackOverflow", this.a);
    }
  }

  //com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:250)
  ExpressionNode a(ExpressionNode paramExpressionNode)
    throws FormulaException
  {
    if (paramExpressionNode == null) {
      return null;
    }
    switch (paramExpressionNode.jdField_for.value())
    {
        ......
        case 30: 
      return jdMethod_for((MultiOperatorNode)paramExpressionNode);


//com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.c.for(SourceFile:1225)
 ExpressionNode jdMethod_for(MultiOperatorNode paramMultiOperatorNode)
    throws FormulaException
  {
    int i = paramMultiOperatorNode.size();
    if (i == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
      ExpressionNode localExpressionNode = a(paramMultiOperatorNode.getOperand(j));//(SourceFile:1225)
      if (localExpressionNode == null) {
        return null;
      }
      paramMultiOperatorNode.setOperand(j, localExpressionNode);
    }
    paramMultiOperatorNode.jdField_try = paramMultiOperatorNode.getOperand(i - 1).jdField_try;

    return paramMultiOperatorNode;
  } 

  //com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:295)
  case 8: 
      return a((FunctionNode)paramExpressionNode);


//com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:3148)
 ExpressionNode a(FunctionNode paramFunctionNode)
    throws FormulaException
  {
    int i = paramFunctionNode.size();
    ExpressionNode[] arrayOfExpressionNode = ArrayPool.a(i, this.a);
    try
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
      {
        ExpressionNode localExpressionNode2 = a(paramFunctionNode.get(j), arrayOfExpressionNode);
        if (localExpressionNode2 == null) {
          return null;
        }
        arrayOfExpressionNode[j] = localExpressionNode2;
      }
      return a(paramFunctionNode, arrayOfExpressionNode);//(SourceFile:3148)
    }
    finally
    {
      ArrayPool.a(arrayOfExpressionNode, this.a);
    }
  }

 //com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.c.a(SourceFile:1809)



//com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:3507)
 FormulaException a(String paramString1, String paramString2, String paramString3, String[] paramArrayOfString, ExpressionNode paramExpressionNode)
  {
    return a(paramString1, paramString2, paramString3, paramArrayOfString, null, paramExpressionNode);
  }

  //com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:3528)
  FormulaException a(String paramString1, String paramString2, String paramString3, String[] paramArrayOfString, Throwable paramThrowable, ExpressionNode paramExpressionNode)
  {
    return new FormulaException(paramString1, paramString2,FormulaResources.a(), paramString3, paramArrayOfString, paramThrowable, this.a, paramExpressionNode);//(SourceFile:3528)
  }


   public FormulaException(String paramString1, String paramString2, CrystalResourcesFactory paramCrystalResourcesFactory, String paramString3, String[] paramArrayOfString, Throwable paramThrowable, FormulaEnvironment paramFormulaEnvironment, ExpressionNode paramExpressionNode)
  {
    super(paramString1, paramString2, paramCrystalResourcesFactory, paramString3, paramArrayOfString, paramThrowable);

    a(paramFormulaEnvironment, paramExpressionNode);
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be an @Override annotation on the implementation of translate?

Comment: I had tried with @Override annotation but nothing was changed.

Comment: if it is not urgent I will look later, currently busy at work if that's ok.

Comment: Thank you very much, when you can from your commitments. Your help will be greatly appreciated, because I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: I had a look and it seems your code is incomplete. On here it is best to post as much as you can in order to allow other users to reproduce your issue. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help if you need assistance, and let me know when you're done updating with those details.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have reported the complete code below

Comment: Sorry, an other question because I don't do it. How can I test a library like that in Eclipse? There isn't main method and I don't know how do it. Thanks a lot

Comment: this code is a part of a library and uses two others libraries to run. One is CrystalReportsRuntime.jar and the second library is CrystalCommon2.jar. Sorry if I'm carring on to add information.

Comment: For future reference, that information should be posted in the OP, particularly the stacktrace. The answer section is not where you should place your info about the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for that. I'm new here, next time I'll write in the OP. I will find out more information about the exception and eventually, I'll ask help for that. Thanks again.

Comment: It's ok, like you said you're new. Some users on here can be quite hostile and impatient because of it, so try your best to conform to the recommended submission guidelines.

Comment: No documentation for this case I found out. I've put the in the OP. If you can help me, or someone because I finished all ideas about that. Thanks again

Comment: You're missing (SourceFile:1809)

Comment: Jd-gui app didn't decompiled that line. I gave an error in that method.

Comment: Then unfortunately we can't help you, everything looks fine up to that point. If we can't see the contents of that method we cannot diagnose the problem.

Comment: thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: View your willingness to and patience in helping me. Since I found out the solution I would like to share it. It was a silly thing. The overload here is missing. Before  ```FormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition[] myArguments = { SimpleFormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition.string };``` After ```FormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition[] myArguments = { SimpleFormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition.string,SimpleFormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition.string };``` Thanks again

Comment: Add it as an answer and set it as accepted. It helps users who have the same problem in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was about this statement:

```
FormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition[] myArguments = {SimpleFormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition.string };
```

The right configuration for the parameters is:

```
FormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition[] myArguments = { SimpleFormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition.string,SimpleFormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition.string };
```

Obviusly in my Crystal Report formula have two String type or one String type, depend on the formula.
Below here the complete code to solve the UFL for a barcode function with two parameters. This code sets UFL library for Crystal Report.

```
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.CrystalResourcesFactory;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.value.FormulaValue;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.value.FormulaValueType;

import com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.value.StringValue;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaFunction;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaFunctionCallException;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaValueReference;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.SimpleFormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition;

public abstract class CodeEAN13Base
   implements FormulaFunction
 {
   FormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition[] myArguments = { SimpleFormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition.string,SimpleFormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition.string };

protected CrystalResourcesFactory resCrystal;



  public CodeEAN13Base()
   {
     this.resCrystal = new CrystalResourcesFactory("Messages");

   }


  protected final String doTranslation(String inputData,String opz)
 // protected final String doTranslation(String inputData)
   {
    String returnVal = "";

   //  returnVal = returnVal + translateCharWrapper(inputData);
     returnVal = returnVal + translateCharWrapper(inputData,opz);


    return returnVal;
   }



   @Override
   public final FormulaValue evaluate(FormulaValueReference[] arguments)
     throws FormulaFunctionCallException
  {

       StringValue dataStringArg = (StringValue)arguments[0].getFormulaValue();
       StringValue opzArg =(StringValue)arguments[1].getFormulaValue();

     String dataString = dataStringArg.getString();
     String opz=opzArg.getString();





    String returnVal = doTranslation(dataString,opz);

    return StringValue.fromString(returnVal);
   }

   @Override
   public final FormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition[] getArguments()
  {
     return this.myArguments;
  }

 @Override  
public final FormulaValueType getReturnType()
  {
     return FormulaValueType.string;
   }


   protected abstract String translate(String inputData,String opz)
   throws InvalidBarcodeDataException;

//protected abstract String translate(String inputData)
//throws InvalidBarcodeDataException;

 // private String translateCharWrapper(String inputData)
   private String translateCharWrapper(String inputData,String opz)
  {
     String returnString;

     try
    {
        // returnString = translate(inputData);
      returnString = translate(inputData,opz);
     } catch (InvalidBarcodeDataException e) {
      returnString = "";
     }

    return returnString;
  }



   @Override
   public void validateArgumentValues(FormulaValueReference[] arguments)
     throws FormulaFunctionCallException
   {}
 }

public class CodeEAN13
  extends CodeEAN13Base
{

    //protected String opz;



   @Override
   public String getIdentifier()
   {
    return "barcodeean13";
  }



  private static String oddBar(String code) {

        return String.valueOf((char)(65+Integer.parseInt(code)));

    }

  private static String evenBar(String code) {

        return String.valueOf((char)(75+Integer.parseInt(code)));

    }


@Override

    protected String translate(String inputData, String opz) throws InvalidBarcodeDataException {   

     Integer checkDigitSubtotal;
     String checkDigit;
      String temp = null;
      String code=inputData;
      String azalea_EAN13 = null;
      String opzM=opz;


//    if(!opzM.equals(null)) {
//     code=code+opzM;
//    }

      //Calculate the EAN-13 check digit.

      checkDigitSubtotal=3*(Integer.parseInt(code.substring(1, 2))+Integer.parseInt(code.substring(3, 4))+Integer.parseInt(code.substring(5, 6))
                           +Integer.parseInt(code.substring(7, 8))+Integer.parseInt(code.substring(9, 10))
                           +Integer.parseInt(code.substring(code.length()-1)));


      checkDigitSubtotal=checkDigitSubtotal+(Integer.parseInt(code.substring(0,1))+Integer.parseInt(code.substring(2, 3))
                                       +Integer.parseInt(code.substring(4, 5))+Integer.parseInt(code.substring(6, 7))
                                       +Integer.parseInt(code.substring(8, 9))+Integer.parseInt(code.substring(10, 11)));

  checkDigit=String.valueOf(300-checkDigitSubtotal);
  checkDigit=checkDigit.substring(checkDigit.length()-1);



 // Begin building the output string with the 1st character's human-readable, L guard bars & odd parity of 1st digit
   temp=(char)(194+Integer.parseInt(code.substring(0,1)))+"x"+oddBar(code.substring(1, 2));  

  // Build the remainder of left half of symbol's parity is based on 1st digit
   switch (code.substring(0,1)) {
   case "0":
      {
         //temp="U|x"; 
         temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(2, 3));
         temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(3, 4));
         temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(4, 5));
         temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(5, 6));
         temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(6, 7));         
      }
    break;
   case "1":
      {
          //temp="[|x";
          temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(2, 3)); 
          temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(3, 4));
          temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(4, 5));
          temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(5, 6));
          temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(6, 7));
      }
      break;
   case "2":
   {
       //temp="V|x";
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(2, 3));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(3, 4));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(4, 5));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(5, 6));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(6, 7));
   }
   break;
   case "3":
   {
       //temp="W|x";
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(2, 3));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(3, 4));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(4, 5));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(5, 6));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(6, 7));
   }
    break;
   case "4":
   {
       //temp="X|x";
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(2, 3));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(3, 4));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(4, 5));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(5, 6));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(6, 7));

   }
   break;
   case "5":
   {
       //temp="Y|x";
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(2, 3));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(3, 4));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(4, 5));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(5, 6));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(6, 7));

   }
   break;
   case "6":
   {
       //temp="Z|x";
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(2, 3));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(3, 4));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(4, 5));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(5, 6));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(6, 7));

   }
   break;
   case "7":
   {
       //temp="u|x";
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(2, 3));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(3, 4));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(4, 5));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(5, 6));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(6, 7));



   }
   break;
   case "8":
   {
       //temp="\\|x";
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(2, 3));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(3, 4));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(4, 5));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(5, 6));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(6, 7));

   }
   break;
   case "9":
   {
       //temp="]|x";
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(2, 3));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(3, 4));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(4, 5));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(5, 6));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(6, 7));

   }
   break;

    default:
   }

////Add the center guard bars & the build right half of symbol using set C (0-9)


    return azalea_EAN13+opzM;
   }




 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete code

```
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaFunction;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaFunctionLibrary;



 public class BarcodeLibrary
   implements FormulaFunctionLibrary
 {
   private final FormulaFunction[] functionArray = {new Code39(), new Code39Ascii(), new CodeI2of5(), new Code2of5()
                                                    ,new CodeC128SetA(),new CodeEAN13()};

   public FormulaFunction getFunction(int functionNumber)
   {
     return this.functionArray[functionNumber];
   }

   public int size()
   {
    return this.functionArray.length;
  }
 }

*************************************************************************
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.CrystalResourcesFactory;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.value.FormulaValue;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.value.FormulaValueType;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.value.StringValue;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaFunction;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaFunctionCallException;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaValueReference;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.SimpleFormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition;

public abstract class CodeEAN13Base
   implements FormulaFunction
 {
   FormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition[] myArguments = { SimpleFormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition.string };

protected CrystalResourcesFactory resCrystal;



  public CodeEAN13Base()
   {
     this.resCrystal = new CrystalResourcesFactory("Messages");

   }


  protected final String doTranslation(String inputData,String opz)

   {
    String returnVal = "";

     returnVal = returnVal + translateCharWrapper(inputData,opz);



    return returnVal;
   }


   @Override
   public final FormulaValue evaluate(FormulaValueReference[] arguments)
     throws FormulaFunctionCallException
  {

       StringValue dataStringArg = (StringValue)arguments[0].getFormulaValue();
       StringValue opzArg =(StringValue)arguments[1].getFormulaValue();

     String dataString = dataStringArg.getString();
     String opz=opzArg.getString();



    String returnVal = doTranslation(dataString,opz);

    return StringValue.fromString(returnVal);
   }

   @Override
   public final FormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition[] getArguments()
  {
     return this.myArguments;
  }

 @Override  
public final FormulaValueType getReturnType()
  {
     return FormulaValueType.string;
   }


   protected abstract String translate(String inputData,String opz)
   throws InvalidBarcodeDataException;

//protected abstract String translateChar(String inputData)
//throws InvalidBarcodeDataException;

 // private String translateCharWrapper(String inputData)
   private String translateCharWrapper(String inputData,String opz)
  {
     String returnString;

     try
    {
        // returnString = translateChar(inputData);
      returnString = translate(inputData,opz);
     } catch (InvalidBarcodeDataException e) {
      returnString = "";
     }

    return returnString;
  }

   @Override
   public void validateArgumentValues(FormulaValueReference[] arguments)
     throws FormulaFunctionCallException
   {}
 }

*************************************************************************
public class CodeEAN13
  extends CodeEAN13Base
{

    protected String opz;



   @Override
   public String getIdentifier()
   {
    return "barcodeean13";
  }



  private static String oddBar(String code) {

        return String.valueOf((char)(65+Integer.parseInt(code)));

    }

  private static String evenBar(String code) {

        return String.valueOf((char)(75+Integer.parseInt(code)));

    }





@Override
protected String translate(String inputData, String opz) throws InvalidBarcodeDataException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Integer checkDigitSubtotal;
  String checkDigit;
      String temp = null;
      String code=inputData;
      String azalea_EAN13 = null;
      Object opzM=opz;

      if(!opzM.equals(null)) {
       code=code+opzM;
      }

      //Calculate the EAN-13 check digit.

      checkDigitSubtotal=3*(Integer.parseInt(code.substring(1, 2))+Integer.parseInt(code.substring(3, 4))+Integer.parseInt(code.substring(5, 6))
                           +Integer.parseInt(code.substring(7, 8))+Integer.parseInt(code.substring(9, 10))
                           +Integer.parseInt(code.substring(code.length()-1)));


  checkDigitSubtotal=checkDigitSubtotal+(Integer.parseInt(code.substring(0,1))+Integer.parseInt(code.substring(2, 3))
                                       +Integer.parseInt(code.substring(4, 5))+Integer.parseInt(code.substring(6, 7))
                                       +Integer.parseInt(code.substring(8, 9))+Integer.parseInt(code.substring(10, 11)));

  checkDigit=String.valueOf(300-checkDigitSubtotal);
  checkDigit=checkDigit.substring(checkDigit.length()-1);



 // Begin building the output string with the 1st character's human-readable, L guard bars & odd parity of 1st digit
   temp=(char)(194+Integer.parseInt(code.substring(0,1)))+"x"+oddBar(code.substring(1, 2));  

  // Build the remainder of left half of symbol's parity is based on 1st digit
   switch (code.substring(0,1)) {
   case "0":
      {
         temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(2, 3));
         temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(3, 4));
         temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(4, 5));
         temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(5, 6));
         temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(6, 7));         
      }
    break;
   case "1":
      {
          temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(2, 3)); 
          temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(3, 4));
          temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(4, 5));
          temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(5, 6));
          temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(6, 7));
      }
      break;
   case "2":
   {
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(2, 3));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(3, 4));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(4, 5));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(5, 6));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(6, 7));
   }
   break;
   case "3":
   {
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(2, 3));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(3, 4));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(4, 5));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(5, 6));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(6, 7));
   }
    break;
   case "4":
   {
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(2, 3));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(3, 4));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(4, 5));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(5, 6));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(6, 7));

   }
   break;
   case "5":
   {
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(2, 3));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(3, 4));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(4, 5));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(5, 6));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(6, 7));

   }
   break;
   case "6":
   {
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(2, 3));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(3, 4));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(4, 5));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(5, 6));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(6, 7));

   }
   break;
   case "7":
   {
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(2, 3));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(3, 4));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(4, 5));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(5, 6));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(6, 7));



   }
   break;
   case "8":
   {
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(2, 3));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(3, 4));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(4, 5));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(5, 6));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(6, 7));

   }
   break;
   case "9":
   {
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(2, 3));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(3, 4));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(4, 5));
       temp=temp+evenBar(code.substring(5, 6));
       temp=temp+oddBar(code.substring(6, 7));

   }
   break;

    default:
   }

////Add the center guard bars & the build right half of symbol using set C (0-9)

    return azalea_EAN13;
   }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A part of the log:

```
1922 [TSLVReader #1] DEBUG com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.Compiler  - Compiling formula {@ean13}...
1922 [TSLVReader #1] INFO com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.Compiler  - Formula {@ean13} did not compile: com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaException: Exception in the formulas '{@ean13}' a 'BarcodeEAN13('412345678901','567')':
the call to a function does not correspond to any overload of barcodeean13.
1922 [TSLVReader #1] WARN com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.ReportDefinition  - com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaException: Exception in the formulas  '{@ean13}' a 'BarcodeEAN13('412345678901','567')':
the call to a function does not correspond to any overload of barcodeean13.
1923 [TSLVReader #1] ERROR com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine  - Formula error: recompile formulas failed
com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaException: Exception in the formulas  '{@ean13}' a 'BarcodeEAN13('412345678901','567')':
the call to a function does not correspond to any overload of barcodeean13.
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:3528)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:3507)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.c.a(SourceFile:1809)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:3148)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:295)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.c.for(SourceFile:1225)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:250)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.do(SourceFile:74)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.c.void(SourceFile:70)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.r.a(SourceFile:90)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaInfo.a(SourceFile:570)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaService.compile(SourceFile:347)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1922 [TSLVReader #1] DEBUG com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.Compiler  - Compiling formula {@ean13}...
1922 [TSLVReader #1] INFO com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.Compiler  - Formula {@ean13} did not compile: com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaException: Exception in the formulas '{@ean13}' a 'BarcodeEAN13('412345678901','567')':
the call to a function does not correspond to any overload of barcodeean13.
1922 [TSLVReader #1] WARN com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.ReportDefinition  - com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaException: Exception in the formulas  '{@ean13}' a 'BarcodeEAN13('412345678901','567')':
the call to a function does not correspond to any overload of barcodeean13.
1923 [TSLVReader #1] ERROR com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine  - Formula error: recompile formulas failed
com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaException: Exception in the formulas  '{@ean13}' a 'BarcodeEAN13('412345678901','567')':
the call to a function does not correspond to any overload of barcodeean13.
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:3528)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:3507)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.c.a(SourceFile:1809)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:3148)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:295)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.c.for(SourceFile:1225)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:250)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.do(SourceFile:74)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.c.void(SourceFile:70)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.r.a(SourceFile:90)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaInfo.a(SourceFile:570)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaService.compile(SourceFile:347)
```

The stacktrace tells you what you need to know, however I am unable to provide more specific information because Crystal Reports appears to be paywalled and they do not offer documentation (at least for free) so I cannot look at the source of the jar.
Regardless, this snippet tells you the majority of what you need to know:

```
1923 [TSLVReader #1] ERROR com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine  - Formula error: recompile formulas failed
com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaException: Exception in the formulas  '{@ean13}' a 'BarcodeEAN13('412345678901','567')':
the call to a function does not correspond to any overload of barcodeean13.
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:3528)
```

This line:

```
com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaException
```

Tells you that the exception thrown is from the Crystal Reports source code, and not a Java specific error. Therefore ***if you can, you should either consult the documentation (if you have access) or inspect the source code to see what conditions cause this to be thrown***. If you are unsure how to do so, you can add some of this information in the question and I or someone else can attempt to provide assistance.

```
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.j.a(SourceFile:3528)
```

The part in brackets tells you where to look for the origin of the exception, SourceFile, likely but not necessarily at line 3528. This line number can be different in practice, particularly if the code you're looking at is decompiled, so if things do not line up as expected you may need to hunt around for the exact line.

Unfortunately without the documentation or source code it will be hard to assist you further.